# CSS Tooltips line break

Tags: html, css

I've text to show inside a tooltip on hover of an icon.
The tooltips width need to be:

- `max-width:300px`
- if the text fit in one line and less than `300px`, adjust to text width
- if the text need many lines, the tooltip width need to be `300px`

How can I define the `.tooltip .content-tooltip` to work like describe before ?
I've tried using `white-space: nowrap;` and some `word-break` ...

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 5px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  margin: 70px auto;
}

.tooltip .content-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: calc(100% + 13px);
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding: 5px 10px 6px;
    display: none;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 300px;
    width: auto;
}

.tooltip:hover .content-tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example</h1>

<span class="tooltip">
  short text
  <span class="content-tooltip">
    Lorem
  </span>
</span>

<span class="tooltip">
  long text
  <span class="content-tooltip">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Nulla nunc massa, eleifend a feugiat ac, varius eu eros.
    Praesent at vulputate risus. Pellentesque dictum pulvinar lectus.
  </span>
</span>

<hr><hr>

<h1>What I expect</h1>

<span class="tooltip">
  short text
  <span class="content-tooltip">
    Lorem
  </span>
</span>

<span class="tooltip">
  long text
  <span class="content-tooltip" style="width: 300px">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Nulla nunc massa, eleifend a feugiat ac, varius eu eros.
    Praesent at vulputate risus. Pellentesque dictum pulvinar lectus.
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: what is the exact question here? where are you stuck? what do you need help with?

Comment: How can I style the `.tooltip .content-tooltip` to be `300px` if the text is on multiples lines, and less with if the text is short ?

Comment: I've added more details.

Comment: The reason its not working because your `.content-tooltip` element resides inside the `.tooltip` element, and since the `.tooltip` has width of 75px, the child `.content-tooltip` is having the width as auto so it takes the available space. Try removing absolute position and transform property and see the result, you'll know what I'm talking about. If you do this, you'll also notice that the short tooltip isn't really taking the shortest width, its taking the same width as the longer tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found myself a solution :

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 5px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  margin: 70px auto;
}
.tooltip .sizing-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: calc(100% + 13px);
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
}
.tooltip .content-tooltip {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px 6px;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.tooltip:hover .sizing-tooltip {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example</h1>

<span class="tooltip">
  short text
  <span class="sizing-tooltip">
    <span class="content-tooltip">
      Lorem
    </span>
  </span>
</span>

<span class="tooltip">
  long text
  <span class="sizing-tooltip">
    <span class="content-tooltip">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Nulla nunc massa, eleifend a feugiat ac, varius eu eros.
      Praesent at vulputate risus. Pellentesque dictum pulvinar lectus.
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by taking out the tooltip from the text content element, and wrapped the tooltip and text content width another div which will act container for both of them, so that tooltip won't take up the width as per the text content instead it will take the width as specified.

This how you should do it:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.text {
    padding: 10px;
}

.tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.text-contianer:hover > .tooltip {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-contianer">
    <div class="text">
        Short
    </div>
    <span class="tooltip">
        Lorem
    </span>
</div>

<div class="text-contianer">
    <div class="text">
        Long
    </div>
    <span class="tooltip">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Nulla nunc massa, eleifend a feugiat ac, varius eu eros.
    Praesent at vulputate risus. Pellentesque dictum pulvinar lectus.
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired solution can be attained if you set a height value to the tooltip.

I see that you've used `max-width`, which is the desirable here but one thing which I guess you missed is that the  default value of `height` for tooltip is `auto`, due to which if you reduce the width of the tooltip, the component will adjust to increase the height. One simple solution as I mentioned is to set a `height` value, and `overflow` to `hidden`

Updated CSS Code:

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  margin: 70px auto;
}

.tooltip .content-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: calc(100% + 13px);
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding: 5px 10px 6px;
    display: none;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 320px;
  height: 15px; //height value set to avoid component auto adjust
  overflow: hidden; //overflow hidden
}

.tooltip:hover .content-tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```