# A large text inside an element with position absolute doesn't grow with its container

Tags: html, css

I have one DIV with position relative and max-width of 100px; its child is a DIV with position absolute and max-width of 550px, this DIV has a large text inside it, this DIV is not fitting the max-width of 550px because its parent has a lower width, so how could I solve this?

This is my code:

```css
.container {
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid black;
   max-width: 100px;
  }

.container .absolute {
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   max-width: 550px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="absolute">
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason for not increasing parent's `max-width`?

Comment: I can't do that because I am making a tooltip, so the parent is just a little text, and then when you hover the mouse it will appear the tooltip with many information, therefore the tooltip should be always larger than the parent.

Comment: Since your parent element has 100px width and its relative and child element is absolute so it will not overflow parent. I have already answered a question with similar scenario.
See if you find this post useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65142784/css-tooltips-line-break/65143264#65143264

Comment: is tooptip your problem? if it is, relative position could be used

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti, in your answer it is working because the text-container has no position relative, I need to use the position relative in the container.

Comment: @SandrinJoy but I need the container has the position relative and the tooltip position absolute.

Comment: You missed the whole point, the text on which you hover isn't the actual container, the text you are going to show and the tooltip has a wrapper which has relative positioning and has width more than the text which you are going to show to the user

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti Now I get it! Yes, this solution works perfectly! Thank you very much!